# "The simplest" way to use a method as a proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Obviously, `method(:method_name).to_proc` works but I'm looking for a more concise way to do it - or I will not be doing it even when it's technically the right thing to do.

I'm contemplating a mix-in defining `to_proc` (just `proc` would be nicer but some genius made it a private method in `Kernel`)

```
module ProcifiedMethods
  def to_proc(sym)
    method(sym).to_proc
  end
end
```

and then call

```
to_proc(:method_name)[*args]
```

but one would think something like that already exists in Ruby core?

My general motivation is to use functional programming concepts interchangeably with OOP. Got a method in some mixin that has no side-effects? Well... use it as a proc! Curry it, compose it, all the other good stuff.

That's the general idea, anyway :)

**QUESTION:** is there a simpler, battle tested, ideally within-ruby-core way to convert methods to procs? (i.e. a more shorthand alias of `method(:method_name).to_proc`).

Comment: I am confused by what you are asking. You are answering your question in your first sentence, then declaring that that is *not* the answer, and then ask your question again … but you have already answered it? *Why* is that not the answer?

Comment: @JörgWMittag because I am not satisfied with the answer. I updated an explicit "QUESTION" segment for all the people who can't be bothered to read the entire text of the question ^_^

Comment: Can you give an objectively verifiable criterion for "simpler, battle tested"? Personally, I don't see how what you have already is not simple nor battle tested. In fact, it is pretty trivial to see that it cannot possibly be any simpler, because in order to turn a method into a proc, you need to 1) get a method and 2) turn it into a proc.

Comment: "simpler" would be "in 1 method call", as opposed to 2 method calls - as you noticed. "battle tested" would be that someone has a gem that does it and that there's an eco system of people doing it in production, I'm a bit wary of playing deep in Ruby internals.

Comment: In that case, it is trivial to see that it cannot possibly be done any simpler, since you have two distinct operations: 1) get a method, 2) turn it into a proc. Sure, you can wrap it into a single method, but then you still have two distinct operations and a grand total of *three* method calls.

Comment: Do you actually need the `to_proc` call? Why not simply `method(:method_name)`, it can be invoked via `method(:method_name)[*args]`.

Comment: I'm sure a java person out there looks at Ruby and thinks the way we turn methods into lambdas is way too verbose. xd

Comment: @Stefan good point! I think that's the answer! `3.method(:+).curry[3] == 6`

Comment: My answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44716976/1983072

@Stefan, if you write something on this, I'll accept your answer <3

Answer (score 4):

If you're using this proc as method argument, you could use `&` unary operator, like `foo(&method(:method_name))`

If method is defined on object, this works too: `foo(&obj.method(:method_name))`

Comment: i think it's a unary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `proc` does something different from `to_proc`. `to_proc` gives you a proc representation of a method. `proc` creates a proc given a block (or using the block with which the method was invoked if no block is given).

Secondly, `method(:name).to_proc` is fairly simple. You can define a method that simplifies it a bit, but for what it does - I would say it is very straight forward.

So for the direct question - No, there is no such way.

---

An argument to be made as for why it has to be slightly more explicit is that unlike with purely functional languages, here the method (and hence the proc) is tied to the instance.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def calculate(baz)
    baz * bar
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
pro = foo.method(:calculate).to_proc

foo.bar = 7
pro.call(6) # => 42
foo.bar = 9
pro.call(6) # => 54
```

Comment: Hm, thank you, that's a shame. One is that they occupied the word "proc" for everybody when there's `lambda`, `->`, `Proc.new`, another is that conversion of methods to procs is syntactically bitter.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#Syntactic_salt

Comment: @bbozo, `lambda` and `->` are different from `proc`. `Proc.new` is the same, but it's more verbose. It happens to want to create a `proc` with a block way more often than it is to want to get a method as a proc.

Comment: True, but I'm really wondering how many people use the `proc` call, or know it exists. I work with Ruby for many years now, I consider myself to be a power user, one that tries to do funny stuff and try new things, but this is my first connection with it. On the other hand, there's a growing eco system combining FP+OOP, having methods relatively interchangeable with procs would go a long way in that direction.

Comment: @bbozo, are you saying that you never use non-lambda procs in Ruby?

Comment: I do when I need to, but I always just did `Proc.new`

Comment: @bbozo, and do you convert methods to procs more often than you create procs?

Comment: it's something I'm playing with now, the currently front-running FP+OOP people in Ruby go heavy-weight in the FP direction (@solnic & others) and they generally leave an impression they'd rather be doing `F#`  -
 something type-safe & purely functional -
 ie "very much not rubyesque" - (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMxurF4oqsc). I'm looking for a more balanced approach for my work.

Comment: "but bbozo if nobody is converting methods to lambdas then why not have a shortcut for `Proc.new`..." - yeah, well, if there's good reason why nobody is doing it then nobody will be doing it, even when it's the natural thing to be doing. The language people are generally wise enough to go in this direction.

Comment: @bbozo, ummmm... wether or not there should be syntax sugar for something should be entirely based on usage. I don't have the time to look at the talk you linked, could you give me the relevant tl;dr? Also edited the answer.

Comment: what's syntactic sugar and what's not is based on "good usage", and promotion of "good usage", not just simple "usage". The relevant tl;dr is a showcase of a blending of FP+OOP in Ruby, one that heavily leans on FP. It's interesting, it's good to know this stuff exists and is around. As someone once put it - if the only thing you have is a hammer, all your problems look like a nail. FP approach in Ruby gives some extra tools and good practices regardless of paradigms (immutability etc).

Comment: @bbozo, I didn't get the tl;dr. You basically said "it's cool/useful to blend FP+OOP in Ruby". Sure... Still missing the relevant part to this question. Also are you saying that creating procs is somehow not "good usage"? Also do you not agree that having a direct shortcut for it might cause some confusion given objects aren't immutable?

Comment: I agree. If it were *that* simple, it would have been done already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147460/discussion-between-bbozo-and-ndn).

Answer (score 0):

Stefan gave a good response, a `Method` behaves like / answers to the same methods as a `Proc`, so the answer is that the simplest way of using a `Method` as a `Proc` is simply using the `Method` which answers to `#call`, `#[]`, `#curry` and all other funny stuff that a `Proc` has.

This makes a `Method` useful for standard FP shennanigans. An example:

```
3.method(:+).curry[3] == 6
```

If anyone is interested, [this is the use case](https://gist.github.com/bbozo/6dc6b86cfd5530ed6bf67877ae6f208d)

Comment: Indeed it does!

Comment: ndn, what? you have some personal bone to pick with this issue? :) Stefan gave a good answer "what you're trying to do is unnecessary because `Method` already duck-types a `Proc`". But OK, I'm done with this issue, and I got my answer.

Comment: I agree, SO is not a 1-person shed, but the question was literally "“The simplest” way to use a method as a proc in Ruby" - not "easiest way to convert a method to a proc", and this is the answer I got, and the one that was intended. I asked the question after not finding the answer searching on SO, so I think it's legitimate.

Comment: In the answer I went overboard, maybe the answer is the thing you have issues with, not the question?

Comment: @ndn, better? :)

Comment: Yep. Now lets delete all the spam comments. xd